# request timed out error while creating User profile service application after long time

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, 2013, profile-sync, synchronisation

in order to configure my sites in sharepoint 2013, we need to start user profile synchronization service. while starting that service it should populate user profile application. for me it is not populating. so im trying to create user profile service application,then im getting this request timed out error.

Comment: My SharePoint 2013 Farm does not have a user profile service application. So, I am trying to create a new User Profile Service Application. But it is failed to create after taking a long time it thrown Request Timed Out Error. Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it step by step:

- Make sure that Farm Administrator account must be a Local
  Administrator on the server where the User Profile Synchronization
  Service will be provisioned.
- Navigate to Central
  Administration >> Application Management >> Manage Service Manage
  Application>> Click on New >> Select

[image]

- Enter Name, Application Pool Name and account

[image]

- Now enter the name of other databases like Social, profile etc. I will leave it by default

[image]

[image]

- Now start the User profile service by going into Central Admin >>
  System Service>> Manage Services on the server
  [image]
- Now start User Profile Synchronization Service by giving the Farm admin credentials

[image]

- Make sure that ForeFront Identity Manager Services (FIM) are correctly configured and started
  [image]
- Perform an IISReset and go get a coffee cup :)
- Now, set up the sync connection by going to Manage Service Application > User Profile Service > Configure Synchronization Connection > Create new Connection (Note sync account in this case, dev_spadaccount must be granted the Create Child Objects (permissions) on the OU you are Syncing with.
  [image]
- Populate the containers and select the required AD's Organization
  Unit to be Synced. Click on and Start the Full Import.
- Remove the Farm account from local admins on the box running FIM

Happy SharePointing!